# implementing prefix operator++

Tags: c++

From http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/97-overloading-the-increment-and-decrement-operators/

Class declaration

```
class Digit
{
private:
    int m_nDigit;
public:
    Digit(int nDigit=0)
    {
        m_nDigit = nDigit;
    }

    Digit& operator++();
    Digit& operator--();

    int GetDigit() const { return m_nDigit; }
};
```

Their implementation of `operator++`

```
Digit& Digit::operator++()
{
    // If our number is already at 9, wrap around to 0
    if (m_nDigit == 9)
        m_nDigit = 0;
    // otherwise just increment to next number
    else
        ++m_nDigit;

    return *this;
}
```

My alternate implementation of `operator++`

```
Digit& Digit::operator++()
{
    return Digit(m_nDigit == 9 ? 0 : (m_nDigit + 1));
}
```

I wanted to know

1. if there are any downsides of creating a new object like I have done, and
2. about how to choose one of these implementations?

Comment: Your alternate implementation looks like it's missing an `=`.

Comment: @CarlNorum: fixed, sorry about that goofup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your alternative implementation you have 2 issues:

1. instead of `m_nDigit = 9` do `m_nDigit == 9`. Currently `m_nDigit` will always be 9, and the return value will always be 0.
2. you're supposed to change the value of `m_nDigit`. When returning 0 - you don't.

The return statement is problematic because the operator is expected to change the value of the operand, not to create a new object.

**edit**

To clarify the problem, consider code:

```
Digit x;
x++;
```

What would you expect `x` to be as the result of this code? I would expect it to be 1. Using your operator, it remains unchanged.

Comment: I have updated the question. What is the problem if it creates a new object?

Comment: @Lazer, you can do whatever you want, but creating a new object is not really in keeping with the normal semantics of the prefix `++` operator.

Comment: @Lazer - the problem is the expectations when someone calls this operator. When I have code like `Digit x; x++;` - what should happen, what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

There certainly are downsides to creating an object as you have done:

1. It will not compile. It is impossible to bind a non-const reference to a temporary.
2. Even if it did compile it would not perform the correct operation (your version makes `operator++` set `m_nDigit` to `9`, the other version increments `m_nDigit`, wrapping around when `10` is reached).
3. Even if it did compile and do the right thing, it would be very unsafe. The returned reference would be bound to a temporary object which would be destroyed before the function returned, this would mean that any attempt to access the object referenced by the return value of `operator++` would result in undefined behaviour.

To choose between the two implementations, you should pick the one which compiles, is correct and is safe.

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem with the ternary operator. Also you are returning a copy of the object not the object itself, and if you are trying to overload the operator to work like a built-in type, you should always return a reference to the object.

I think you should do it like this:

```
Digit& Digit::operator++()
{
    m_nDigit = (m_nDigit == 9 ? 0 : m_nDigit++);
    return *this;
}
```

Or like this:

```
Digit& Digit::operator++()
{
    m_nDigit = (++m_nDigit % 10);
    return *this;
}
```

The downside of creating a new object is that in code like:

```
Digit d;
++d;
```

I would expect the value of d to change and with a new object it doesn't. This operator is in many cases used like this (without assigning it to a variable) so if you don't increase and return the same object, you can't use it like that.

Answer (score 2):

1. `m_nDigit = 9` is an assignment and will always be evaluated to `true`.
2. You return a copy of the object but return type is a reference. This may bite you (see [Is returning a temp-object by reference possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714874/is-returning-a-temp-object-by-reference-possible)).
3. Why not `m_nDigit = (m_nDigit + 1) % 9;`?